# It is required to turn on the LED if the distance to the object is less than or equal to 200 centimeters. Find the error in the code

Tags: arduino-uno, hc-sr04

```
int trigPin = 10;

const int echoPin = 8;

int led = 7;

const int distance = 200;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
    int duration, cm;
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
    cm = duration/58;
    if (cm < distance)
    {
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    }
    else
    {
        digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    }
    delay(100);
}
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your problem with the code? Or is that a  school excercise?

Comment: I can't find the error in the code myself.

Comment: How do you know, that there is an error. Give us a description of your problem

Comment: Tested via https://www.tinkercad.com. Does not work correctly, did not complete the task.

Comment: In the image trigger is connected to pin 9, your code says pin 10. Does it solve your problem if you use the correct pin?

Comment: please describe the problem ... what does it do? ... `Does not work correctly` is a useless description of a problem

Comment: *Does not work correctly* - OK you've said what it doesn't do. What **does** it do? Does the LED light up or not?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have `trigPin` as pin 10, however your wiring diagram shows it connected to pin 9, so that won't work.
2. `pulseIn` returns an `unsigned long` (microseconds) - see [pulseIn](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/pulsein/). You are collecting the results in an `int` which has a maximum value of 32767. The value may be overflowing and thus not be correct.